# How to remove shipping cost from shipping method label? woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove the shipping cost from the shipping method label.

[image]

Is there some code to remove  the cost?

Thanks.

I have tried to use this method:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'remove_local_pickup_free_label', 10, 2 );
  function remove_local_pickup_free_label($full_label, $method){
     $full_label = str_replace("USD","HKD",$full_label);
 return $full_label;
}
```

---

Solution:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label','remove_local_pickup_free_label', 10, 2 );
 function remove_local_pickup_free_label($full_label, $method){
   $full_label = substr( $full_label, 0, strpos( $full_label, ':'));
   return $full_label;
}
```

Comment: find the class and do display:none with a custom css plugin

Comment: It cannot use `css` to remove it. As the cost is stick with the shipping address. If I use `css` to remove it, all the address will be removed...

Answer (score 0):

This is from the Woocommerce support page

```
/**
 * Remove shipping name from the label in Cart and Checkout pages
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'wc_custom_shipping_labels', 10, 2 );
function wc_custom_shipping_labels( $label, $method ) {
    if ( $method->cost > 0 ) {
        if ( WC()->cart->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ) {
            $label = wc_price( $method->cost );
            if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && WC()->cart->prices_include_tax ) {
                $label .= ' <small>' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        } else {
            $label = wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() );
            if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && ! WC()->cart->prices_include_tax ) {
                $label = ' <small>' . WC()->countries->inc_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        }
    }

    return $label;
}
```

You can adapt the above code and use it to hide the actual price from the label. Don't forget to use a child theme and add this on `functions.php`